# Возможно ли включить облачное хранилище в vs code для файлов проекта?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Есть ли такая функция в vs code как, например, в microsoft one drive или google disk, чтобы vs code сохранял файлы, которые у него лежат в проекте?
Просто не хочу, чтобы файлы потерялись, если комп сломается.

Comment: git вам в помощь

Comment: а может все таки нужно расширение вида Remote - SSH
(ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) и код можно хранить на удаленном сервере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте средства контроля версий приложений [git](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) можно настроить приватный либо публичные репозитории на различных серверах (Git-хостинг:  GitHub, Codebase, SourceForge, SourceHut, Gitorious, Bitbucket, GitLab). Это даже больше приветствуется для демонстрации ваших работ у потенциальных работодателей. А VS Code из коробки хорошо управляется с git